Can the zero article be used with "university class"?
I have a letter I am responding to, in which I reply to an anecdote originally detailed by the recipient. In this anecdote, the person talks about getting kicked out of class due to some kind of behavior they exhibited. I responded, in part, by asking the following:

That wasn't university class, was it?

Normally, I would not have given this sentence a second thought, but Grammarly insisted that there should be an article preceding "university", namely "a." This got me thinking as to whether my sentence was grammatically sound on its own; it wouldn't be the first time I've disagreed with a Grammarly correction. My reasoning as to why there should not be an "a" there is because of the original ambiguity about whether this happened across different classes or just one, where the current phrasing I use sort of has this ambiguous pluralization to it (if that's even a thing). I would love it if anyone could steer me in the right direction. Additionally, if there are other grammatical mistakes in my question, both this Stack Exchange one and the one I'm referencing, please correct me.
EDIT: In the letter I received, this individual also used "class" without a determiner. Additionally, the letter writer is from the UK whereas I am from the US.

I'd certainly expect the "a" there. Regardless of whether it was for the session or the course, "class" is singular and so requires something there. You could say "your university class" if you really insist on not using "a."

Might be different in British English than in American English,

You write a lot of words but don't explain what you were asking. Did you want to know if the class they were kicked out of was a university class, or are you using "class" to mean an abstract standard or level of behaviour?

I intended to inquire if the class (or classes) were attended at university, as opposed to high school, middle school, etc. It was not intended to be an ambiguous usage of the word class.

One can find the occasional single-form noncount usage in reasonable-looking articles:


CSU counts a semester of college class as one year in their A-G count ....                                                   [Talk.College Confidential]




Calling all students: here's what you can expect for your first day of college class. Don't know what to expect for your first day of
school ....
                                  [fastweb]




Calendar days begin and include the first day of college class, Saturdays, Sundays and holidays.                                                                     [Delta
College]




Can I sue for being wrongfully dropped from college class?                   [AVVO]


and an obviously telegraphese (headlinese) deleted form:


Student barred from college class for rejecting 'the reality of white male privilege'                                                         [The Washington
Times]


These all obviously use 'class' in the 'course of class lessons' sense rather than the 'Monday's French class/lesson' sense. And in informal situations, I believe the usage is at least borderline acceptable. Though note that the examples here all have a preposition before the NP.
But all the examples Collins Dictionary gives include a determiner (his / the / a) and often attributive nouns. They all seem to be in a formal register. And I'd recommend that an article (or other determiner, such as 'your') be included in all but informal contexts.

The "Can I sue" example sounds wrong to me. The others are referring to classes in general, not a specific class, except the headline.

I assumed 'kicked out of class' meant a permanent sanction.

To me, "kicked out of class" means being kicked out of the classroom where the class is taking place, while "kicked out of a class" means removed from enrollment in the class.

'Louisiana child kicked out of class because parents are same-sex couple.
Parents said they were told she ‘wouldn’t be able to go to school there any more because of our lifestyle choices’ A Louisiana five-year-old was allegedly forced out of her kindergarten class at a religious school because her parents are a same-sex couple.' (Guardian; 2022) But there are admittedly far more examples meaning 'ejected from a lesson'.

For the excerpt: "Calling all students: here's what you can expect for your first day of college class." is it necessarily the case that this is meant to be interpreted with a dropped "a"-determiner? The way I interpret "first day of college class" is sort of a superposition of "first day of a college class" and "first day of college classes." I guess to me, the sentence references an arbitrary number of classes which could be a singular class or could be two or more classes.

I'd say it's a noncount usage (though it's moot whether some usages – look at 'weigh anchor'; 'break camp' – should be classed as either count/noncount),  'That wasn't a university class, was it?' is count, as 'I was in two university classes at the start of term' is available for separate courses. // Note that 'expelled from school' and 'sent down from university' are certainly acceptable, and there's no hint of an article here. 'Kicked out of course' isn't ... I'm assuming 'kicked out of class' mimics the previous two examples, with 'class' meaning the course involved.


My reasoning as to why there should not be an "a" there is because of the original ambiguity about whether this happened across different classes or just one, where the current phrasing I use sort of has this ambiguous pluralization to it (if that's even a thing).

"The original ambiguity about whether this happened across different classes or just one" isn't related to the issue of whether to use "class" with or without a determiner.
For example, you said:

In this anecdote, the person talks about getting kicked out of class due to some kind of behavior they exhibited.

Did you have no determiner before class because you intended it to have some "ambiguity about whether this happened across different classes or just one"? I don't think you did.

I think the article is preferred in yuor sentence. Without the article, it sounds like "university class" is being used as an adjective, meaning something that's fit for a university, as in:

Q. How good is that textbook?
A. It's university class.

However, this interpretation is only possible in particular contexts. It wouldn't be expected after the person said he was kicked out of the class (except remotely in a sarcastic way, meaning that kicking him out is not characteristic of a university).

Not in context.

True, I've added some clarification.
